# Make it easier to see that a post is a community wiki in the ios app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, community-wiki

I was browsing Meta Stack Overflow on the iOS app, and a faq-proposed question got a new answer.  I was about to comment that the answer should be made into a community wiki, but then I checked the [edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/303244/revisions) (in the app) and saw that the post was created as a community wiki.

But there is no useful indication on the post itself that it was a community wiki.  It's only because of the context of the faq-proposed tag that I even thought to look if the post was a community wiki.

[image: iOS screen cap]

As you can see, the post appears to be completely owned by the original author, who also created most of the the current content for the community wiki.  This is inconsistent with the standard view, which shows the largest contributor, but replaces that user's reputation and badges with a percentage of their contributions.

Please make the views more consistent between the iOS app and the main site for community wikis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be in the next build.

> [image: Screenshot showing community wiki answer with "community wiki" instead of posting user]