# Community Wiki posts in the iOS app don’t mention the original author

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app, community-wiki

Just noticed in the iOS app: Community Wiki posts de-emphasise the original author to the point of not listing them at all.

Here’s an example from [a thread on Meta.SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6441/3567):

[image]

There’s nothing on the screen to indicate who originally wrote this post (which in this case, is particularly relevant).

About a month ago, [Community Wiki posts were changed in the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264167/226928) to de-emphasise the original author, but I think it’s gone too far. Here, for comparison, is the same post in my browser:

[image]

The original author is still listed, but without their rep and/or avatar. I’d like to see this subtler form of attribution in the iOS app – indeed, there’s a blank space below the “Community Wiki” text that looks like it was meant for just such an attribution. It would be more consistent with the website, and this information is often useful.

Poking around a few different Stacks suggests this is a problem with all CW posts, not SFF-specific.

---

- App Version: 1.4.0
- Device: iPhone8,1
- OS Version: Version 9.0.2 (Build 13A452)

Comment: From a technical standpoint, the author shouldn't always appear there. Community wiki posts display the user who has contributed the most content to it. The app isn't given any data that it could determine such information, which might be why we opted to just not show a user at all. Displaying the author would make the app still-inconsistent with what information it displays.

Answer (score 3):

As animuson mentioned in the comments, community wikis don't always show the original author on the web.  When edits have been made by multiple users, it shows statistical information like "14 revs, 8 users 31% unknown"

> [image: Screenshot of community wiki post with above statistical information.]

Since the app doesn't automatically pull revision information when displaying posts, I don't show anything here.  That said, you can find a full revision history for community wiki posts by tapping "Answered" or "Edited" below the post:

> [image: Screenshot highlighting the tap area to get revisions.]
>
> [image: Screenshot showing revision history for post.]